# "She knows how to drive a motor cycle" vs. "She knows how to drive motor cycle" which one is correct?

Tags: articles

I had to choose the correct sentence from five given sentences. Three were obviously wrong. I chose "She knows how to drive a motor cycle" which appeared to be the wrong answer; the "correct" answer missed out the article *a*.

Can anyone explain why am I wrong?

Comment: What were the other three options? Who created the original question & answers?

Comment: The other three options are:
1. She knows driving motor cycle.
2. She knows how motor cycle to drive.
3. She knows how drive a motor cycle.

Obviously, any of these three options doesn't follow the grammar rule. So I didn't post it.

Comment: You are not wrong. Many tests are wrong. Fortunately, the conventions of grammar are not set by any one quiz.

Comment: I'd **guess** (not being American) that the "correct" answer was formed by analogy from "She knows how to play piano" or some such. That's not always the right thing to do.

Comment: You are not wrong (though in my British English we would say "She knows how to _ride_ a motorcycle".

Comment: The "correct" answer would appar to be a mistake.